# android layout inspector don't show in preview not working

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

In android studio when we use layout inspector we have a hierarchy viewer panel on the left. I see in tutorials if we right click on view in hierarchy viewer we have a disable show in preview item which makes preview disable.
but in my android studio 2.2.3 when I right click on view nothing happen.Are there any settings I should set? am I missing something?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It seems right click on layouts in layout inspector not working in android studio in windows only I tryed in ubuntu and its working, I see in tutorials work in mac just in poor windows not working.

Comment: it says unsupported for api < 23